# how to do $\limsup$/$\liminf$ of a subset sequence (with an exemple)

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My prof give us this exercise:

**With these definitions:**

$$E' := \liminf_{k\rightarrow \infty}\; E_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} E_n$$

$$E'' := \limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty}\;E_k = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} E_n$$

**Let** $E_n = \left\{x \in [0,2\pi] : \dfrac{\sin(nx)}n > 0\right\}$ with $n\in \Bbb N$.

**Calculate: $E', E''$**

but in class he never did exemples on how to proceed in calculate limsup, liminf of subset sequences, he only gave us the definitions.

Could anyone explain me how to do this? (I posted this exemple to give you something concrete for a better explaining).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: **Hint**: First note $$E_n = \{x : \sin(nx) > 0\}$$Then try to write down explicitly (as a union of intervals).

Comment: @Alex: Not every question containing the term "set" is about [set-theory].

Comment: @Alex: Yes, those are limits of sequences of sets. Still not set theory, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, okay. I'm not a specialist in that area so I assume you are right. Let's delete the waste comments.